# How is $M^*\otimes M$ identified with $\text{End}(M)$ in the category of $R$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, modules, tensor-products

I'm new to tensor products and I'm trying to figure out how $M^*\otimes M$ is identified with $\text{End}(M)$ in the category of $R$-modules, where $M$ is a free $R$-module of finite rank and $M^*=\text{Hom}(M,R)$.

My attempt is to identify $m^*\otimes m$ with the endomorphism $n\mapsto m^*(m)n$. However, this identification is not bijective because it maps any $m^*\otimes m$ to a diagonal matrix. I am quite confused here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of the more general identification
$$
M^* \otimes P \cong \operatorname{Hom}(M, P), 
$$
which is also a natural isomorphism via the bijection generated by
$$
m^* \otimes p \;\longmapsto\; (n \mapsto m^*(n)\,p)
$$
for all $n \in M$ and extended linearly. In the special case where $P = M$, this looks like
$$
m^* \otimes m \;\longmapsto\; (n \mapsto m^*(n)\,m).
$$

Comment: It might be interesting to note that your canonical map in one direction is also an isomorphism in the more general case that $M$ is projective and finitely generated.